# Destinations with a tradition of elopement

Tags: where-on-earth, destinations, weddings

What are some destinations with a tradition of elopement?

[Gretna Green](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gretna_Green) is a good example of this - it used to be the go-to destination for elopers in the UK, because laws in Scotland were less strict than those in England and Wales, and it was the first town over the border. It's mentioned in Pride and Prejudice along with other novels. Weddings were often done by blacksmiths rather than priests, and many weddings are still done over an anvil.

An equivalent in the United States is [Las Vegas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_weddings), often performed by an Elvis impersonator.

However, I'm not limiting myself to western countries. I'd be interested not only in specific towns associated with elopements, but also cultures where elopement has some tradition associated with it, so long as they are open to tourists doing such elopements.

In my case, it'd be an opposite-sex elopement, not a same-sex elopement.

Related question: [Can you get married while traveling?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/can-you-get-married-while-traveling)

**Background** In case anyone's wondering, I'm not trying to get married without the knowledge of my parents. I'm wanting to know because weddings are getting too big and expensive nowadays.

Comment: Does it have to be a church-led ceremony and in that case what religion? I'm thinking there might be something for you in the way of civil weddings.

Comment: No religious requirements. Also, I'm an Australian citizen.

Comment: So it's not an actual problem you're facing right now? [faq]

Comment: It's also currently way too broad.  I'm sure we could come up with reasons to go to several dozen countries, and within those, dozens (and in some cases hundreds) of cities.  Even 'close to Australia' is rather broad...

Comment: Voted to close, seems too open ended to me.

Comment: This is US centric but City Hall comes to mind....

Comment: Are we talking about normal heterosexual marriage here? Many countries do not allow homosexual marriages if that is your case.

Comment: IMHO, you could edit this question to be more specific. There can be hundreds of places, depending, where you want to elope from.

Comment: The word 'eloping' implies an impromptu or secret wedding. Are you looking for that or just a wedding without many people and the the traditional (Western) ceremonies?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered Indonesia? Bali is a popular tourist destination for Australasians and is also has a reputation for couples looking to have a smaller, less expensive wedding. I'm not sure whether that means that Indonesia would be considered a common place for elopement, but given your background comment, it would appear that you are more interested in limiting costs.

Regarding the legalities of getting married in Indonesia, [this site](http://www.balimystical.com/) has some information. I can't attest to its veracity in this regard.

An alternative is Rarotonga. Friends of mine (New Zealand residents) got married there fairly recently. A brief internet search offers this as an [example site](http://www.experiencerarotonga.co.ck/ToursActivities/Weddings.aspx) giving the fine print regarding getting married in Rarotonga.

**Note that I have no connection with these or any other commercial site dealing with travel, weddings, or the legalities of marrying overseas.**