# Same sex marriage in USA on visit/tourist visa?

Tags: usa, legal, tourist-visas, weddings, lgbt

I am Sri Lankan male to female transgender person (but my travel document still lists me as male) and have a boyfriend from the United States. Can we get married in the USA on a visit visa or tourist visa?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it does not make sense and is off topic.

Comment: The question makes sense and mostly boils down to "can I get married in the US on a tourist visa?" with an extra potential complication. The [short answer](https://www.prideimmigration.com/marry-us-citizen-tourist-visa/) is "theoretically," but there are problems with that approach. Do you plan to live in the US after the wedding or leave promptly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you get married while traveling?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4292/can-you-get-married-while-traveling)

Comment: In addition, it appears, unfortunately, you'd [probably not have the marriage be recognized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_rights_in_Sri_Lanka#Family_and_marriage) in Sri Lanka, which could lead to legal and possibly tax complications. The most prudent thing to do would be to hire a qualified US immigration attorney to apply for a spousal visa on your behalf, especially if you plan to live in the United States after the wedding.

Comment: Note that it is, in fact, of course perfectly OK **"to get married"** if you are in the US on a tourist visa.  Like, they don't look at you (or the other party) before you "get married" and say, oh, you're on a tourist visa, you can not get married.  (!)  So yes you can (of course) "get married" when you're in the US on a tourist visa.  The question may be more about, can you then get a green card, what will it mean in your home country, etc etc.

Comment: @JoeBlow while you are correct, it appears that many people think that it *isn't* allowed to get married as a tourist in the US, perhaps because they are confused by things like K visas that are irrelevant in most cases (but might be relevant here). To dispel that notion I usually cite the fact that New York City actually has an information sheet for people coming as tourists to get married.

Comment: phoog - fair enough!

Comment: @JoeBlow Maybe many of those people think it is not allowed to marry as a tourist is because in other countries you have to be a resident at least to marry, in some countries you can only marry in the town where one of the couple is registered.

Comment: I've heard of the potential for trouble at the border. If you show up and tell them you're getting married, CBP is going to question your intent to leave fairly seriously.

Comment: @Willeke I guess you are quite right.

Answer (score 5):

The same-sex part of your situation is irrelevant in the US.

The issue for you will be, if the plan is you enter the US on a tourist visa, marry, then apply to change your visa status on the grounds you are married to an US citizen.  If you do that, ICE will suspect you of visa fraud -- and [they will likely be right](https://www.prideimmigration.com/marry-us-citizen-tourist-visa/).

If you want to come to the US to get married and then stay, apply for a [fiancée visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/immigrate/family/fiance-k-1.html).

If you want to come to the US to get married and then return to Sri Lanka, a tourist visa is fine, but your marriage will not be recognized under Sri Lankan law.